# Can't create subset strings from parent data

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string, numpy

I am trying to create subset lists from a parent list but something is not parsable in its structure

```
not_pronouns = set(entail_label) - set(gender_neutral_entails)
```

unhashable type: 'dict'

```
print(gender_neutral_entails[0])
print(entail_label[0])


{'premise': 'A person on a horse jumps over a broken down airplane.', 'hypothesis': 'A person is outdoors, on a horse.', 'label': 0}
{'premise': 'A person on a horse jumps over a broken down airplane.', 'hypothesis': 'A person is outdoors, on a horse.', 'label': 0}
```

How should I save the rows that are in entail_label but not in its child gender_neutral_entails ?

```
not_pronouns = [x for x in entail_label if x not in gender_neutral_entails]
```

this is very slow and takes forever to iterate over 500k examples

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: If I have two lists a parent and child and i want to save the residual of a-b, how can i do that

Comment: Each list element is of the form 

{'premise': 'A person on a horse jumps over a broken down airplane.', 'hypothesis': 'A person is training his horse for a competition.', 'label': 1}

Comment: I have updated the question with exactly what I am trying

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Not sure how to further describe it. Trying to extract the difference between 2 lists where each list has a dictionary in it